# Copy the colored rows which are conditionally formatted to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have excel spreadhseet which is conditionally formatted with different colors after comparing the Days from the TAT value.

Now, I want to copy each colored rows to different sheet and name the sheets.

I agree this can be achieved by filtering the colors manually, can it be done by VBA code ?

The data is placed in 6th row of the sheet.

Also the conditionally formatted colors may change in future so the code should overwrite the colored rows which are placed in different sheets.

Please confirm and reply with a solution if this can be acheived through VBA code.

Please find the below image for more understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your starting point.

```
Sub Test() 
    Range("A1").Select 
    Selection.AutoFilter 
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$" & Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0 _ 
    , 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor 
    Range("$A$1:$D$" & lastr).Select 
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Red"
    Sheets("Red").select
    Range("A" & Range("A" & rows.count).end(XlUp).row).Select 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you giving a solution with VBA code, I have added a line to select the end of the row, however you gave perfect solution for the same, the conditionally formatted colors in current sheet will change in future, so when I filter it again and copy to the red sheet through VBA it should keep the old data and add the new data below the existing data whether this can be acheieved ?

Comment: `Range("A" & Range("A") & rows.count).end(XlUp).row).Select ` have added this line and modified the code above to account for that. Previously it was `Range("A1").Select` hence it was overwriting. The first line basically finds the last Row in Column A

Comment: I tried adding the line `Range("A" & Range("A") & rows.count).end(XlUp).row).Select` in the code but it gives an error in the `.row).select`, what needs to be changed there ?

Comment: Small mistake with the closing bracket if you notice there was a closing closing bracket after the second "A") which shouldn't be there have amended the code in the post

Comment: Yes it works fine:-), Suppose if I re-run the code it will show the error as the Red, Orange and green sheets are already added, can I avoid this error so that I can add the new colored data in the Red sheet ?